# Intellij: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release [Help 1]

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, intellij-plugin

I am really new to this. I am trying to push my GitHub code to Heroku for a discord bot. When I push my code to Heroku, I get the error saying  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project : Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
I am on Java 14.0.2

[This is my pom.xml and you can see the external library on left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/707dD.png)

[My preferences are all set to 14.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiyIN.png)

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqqCK.png)

[My maven runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJZV7.png)

I have also deleted my .m2/repository.
I am sorry if this has been posted before or if this is really dumb.
Thank You in Advance if anyone replies.

Comment: First no images better use text...(copy & past)...second there does not exist a release `14.0.2` only `14`....

Comment: I added 14 and when I do mvn clean compile it says build is successful. I updated my post. Please check it out. and thank you for that I really appreciate it man.